# yii and session variables

Tags: php, session, yii

Currently working within Yii framework.
I am trying to set a temp array of 16 numbers and refresh the page.  However; I ran into a small issue and was trying to find an alternative way of solving this.  Currently I was trying to save the array as an attribute in the model, but now I know that can not be done.  What I need to do is set a temp variable, check for that temp variable, handle the page accordingly, and then delete the temp variable.  I have been reading about Session variables, and it seems like that would be my first choice.

My Questions:

1) Is Session the way to go/Is there a better way?

2) Is Yii using a session, and if so, will I break that?

if(1 && 2){ 3) What is the proper way to instantiate an array in a session and delete it?; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setState()`, `hasState()` and `getState()` methods of the `CWebUser` class.

```
//to set the random values
Yii::app()->user->setState('random_key', $theValues);

//to check if the key exists
if (Yii::app()->user->hasState('random_key')) { echo true; }

//to get the random values back
$my_values = Yii::app()->user->getState('random_key');
```

[Here's the link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser) the the `CWebUser` class reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$_SESSION` global, but its recommended to use `Yii::app()->user->setState()` or `getState()`. You have to enable yii sessions in your config in order to use it.

Take a look in the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/).